# Python decorated class documentation

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, docstring

I'm using a decorator for singletons in python, implemented as shown below.

I'd like to have the pydoc of the decorated class being exactly the same as the pydoc of the non decorated class, but I don't find how:

- Without the `getSingletonInstance.__doc__ = cls.__doc__` line, the pydoc of the decorated class gives the pydoc of the `singleton` function.
- With the `getSingletonInstance.__doc__ = cls.__doc__` line, the pydoc of the decorated class gives only the "top level" docstring.

How can I proceed?

Thanks.

```
def singleton(cls):
    """A singleton decorator

    Warnings
    --------
    Singleton gdecorated calsses cannot be inhehited

    Example
    -------
    >>> from decorators import singleton
    >>> @singleton
    ... class SingletonDemo():
    ...     pass
    >>> d1 = SingletonDemo()
    >>> d1.a = 0xCAFE
    >>> d2 = SingletonDemo()
    >>> id(d1) == id(d2)
    True
    >>> d1 == d2
    True
    >>> d2.a == 0xCAFE
    True

    References
    ----------
    See case 2 of https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#examples
    """
    _instances = {}

    def getSingletonInstance():
        if cls not in _instances:
            _instances[cls] = cls()
        return _instances[cls]

    getSingletonInstance.__doc__ = cls.__doc__

    return getSingletonInstance
```

Comment: No no no no no no no no. Never write a decorator that replaces a class with a function. `type(SingletonDemo()) is SingletonDemo`? `False`. `isinstance(SingletonDemo(), SingletonDemo)`? `TypeError`. `class SingletonSubclass(SingletonDemo):`? Also `TypeError`. When you're decorating a class, return a class. Ideally, the same class.

Comment: Thanks Aran-Fey, but ... well, I've seen many ideas for singletons, and none are perfect. And the python manifesto says "Although practicality beats purity.".

But if you have a better solution, I'll be happy to learn ;-) I just don't want to have to invoke a `getInstance` class method or something similar every time I need an instance, but I would like to always be able to use `MyClass()` transparently.

Comment: Why not just make the instance a module-level global, and prevent creating more instances? You may be familiar with the core Python singleton `None`, which you have never accessed by calling a constructor. You just write `None`.

Comment: Indeed @user2357112, but it means that instances will be created every time modules will be imported. And I don't want to create instances if they are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `functools.wraps`:

```
import functools

def wrapper(cls):
    _instances = {}
    class inner(cls):
        def __new__(subcls):
            if subcls not in _instances:
                _instances[subcls] = object.__new__(subcls)
            return _instances[subcls]
    inner.__doc__=cls.__doc__
    return inner

@wrapper
class A(object):
    """Example Docstring"""
    def method(self):
        """Method Docstring"

A.__doc__
# "Example Docstring"
A.method.__doc__
# "Method Docstring"
```

Comment: Thanks @mousetail, but it gives the same as `getSingletonInstance.__doc__ = cls.__doc__`: only the "top level" doc string, not the full class documentation

Comment: @MichaelHooreman I have updated my answer. It should work now

Comment: Great! It only misses the constructor call. It's kind of spaghetti code, but I had to call it using `_instances[cls].__init__()` just after `_instances[cls] = object.__new__(cls)`. Unfortunately, `isinstance(A(), A)` still returns `False`

Comment: @MichaelHooreman I tried it and `isinstance` works properly for me.

Comment: Indeed, I've called `__new__(cls)` instead of `__new__(subclass)`. Sorry. I've made a summary on "another" solution below.

Comment: It seems that the constructor is called every time. Found a solution which I'll push in another "solution" for this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Answer summarizing all the discussions, with example.
Thanks a lot to everybody.

This solution:

- Preserves the docstring
- Preserves the type
- Supports static and class methods

Limitations:

- Singletons cannot be inherited, which is meaningful regarding to the context

Solution:
    def singleton(cls):

```
    """A singleton decorator

    Warnings
    --------
    Singleton decorated classes cannot be inhehited

    Example
    -------
    >>> import abc
    >>> 
    >>> @singleton
    ... class A():
    ...     "Ad-hoc documentation of class A"
    ...     def __init__(self):
    ...         "Ad-hoc documentation of class A constructor"
    ...         print("constructor called")
    ...         self.x = None
    ...     @classmethod
    ...     def cm(cls):
    ...         "a class method"
    ...         print("class method called")
    ...     def im(self):
    ...         "an instance method"
    ...         print("instance method called")
    ...     @staticmethod
    ...     def sm():
    ...         "a static method"
    ...         print("static method called")
    ... 
    >>> @singleton
    ... class P(abc.ABCMeta):
    ...     @abc.abstractmethod
    ...     def __init__(self):
    ...         pass
    ... 
    >>> class C(P):
    ...     def __init__(self):
    ...         print("C1 constructor called")
    ... 
    >>> a1 = A()
    constructor called
    >>> a1.x = 0xCAFE
    >>> a1.x
    51966
    >>> a2 = A()
    >>> a2.x
    51966
    >>> a1.x == a2.x
    True
    >>> a1 == a2
    True
    >>> id(a1) == id(a2)
    True
    >>> type(a1) == type(a2)
    True
    >>> isinstance(a1, A)
    True
    >>> ta1 = type(a1)
    >>> issubclass(ta1, A)
    True
    >>> A.cm()
    class method called
    >>> a1.cm()
    class method called
    >>> A.sm()
    static method called
    >>> a1.sm()
    static method called
    >>> a1.im()
    instance method called
    >>> try:
    ...     C()
    ... except Exception as e:
    ...     type(e)
    ... 
    <class 'TypeError'>

    """
    _instances = {}
    _constructorCalled = []
    class inner(cls):
        def __new__(subcls):
            if subcls not in _instances:
                _instances[subcls] = cls.__new__(subcls)
            return _instances[subcls]
        def __init__(self):
            if type(self) not in _constructorCalled:
                cls.__init__(self)
                _constructorCalled.append(type(self))
        __init__.__doc__ = cls.__init__.__doc__
        __new__.__doc__ = cls.__new__.__doc__
        if __new__.__doc__ == (
            "Create and return a new object.  "
            "See help(type) for accurate signature."
        ):
            __new__.__doc__ = "Returns a singleton instance"
    inner.__doc__ = cls.__doc__
    return inner
```